# how to get json's filtered data in vue js form's v-model property? for update

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

```
      async getData() {
        let result = await axios.get('/restaurant/')
        console.warn(result.data.data)
        //  this.list = result.data.data;
        this.list = JSON.stringify(result.data.data);
        var data = JSON.parse(this.list);
        this.restaurant = data.filter(d => d.restaurantId === 2);
        console.warn(this.restaurant)
    }
```

> i'm trying to use this.restaurant's data in my v-model

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="this.restaurant.restaurantName" id="recipient-name">
 </div
```

Comment: JSON is a text format; `this.list` is a string in JSON format. `data` is an array. JSON has little to do with this question. I'm not sure what the question here is, but from my understanding, Vue, like other SPA frameworks, doesn't use `this.` when referring to properties.

Comment: also, `this.restaurant` will be an Array ... perhaps you want `this.restaurant = data.find(d => d.restaurantId === 2);` - also, you really don't need to stringify then parse the data